# Can't save files to second hard drive

Tags: partitioning, permissions, firefox

I just bought a new laptop with a 512GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. I installed Ubuntu on the SSD (using UEFI) and left the HDD for storage. I had Windows on it, but I deleted it. It had two recovery partitions left and an EFI partition. I assigned most of the left over space as an ext4 partition to use for data, with mountpoint `/BHDD`. I left 100GB as unallocated in case I decide to revive Windows). I created symbolic links to my Documents, Pictures, Downloads and Music folders in my home directory. However, I can't download files to them - I get an error "Invalid Save permissions". I can create and delete folders or text files on `/BHDD`.

I am really confused what is wrong.

**Edit:** Output from `ls -l ~`

```
total 28  
drwxr-xr-x 2 bogdan bogdan 4096 Aug 27 19:22 Desktop  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bogdan bogdan   22 Aug 26 21:29 Documents -> /BHDD/bogdan/Documents  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bogdan bogdan   22 Aug 26 21:30 Downloads -> /BHDD/bogdan/Downloads  
-rw-r--r-- 1 bogdan bogdan 8980 Aug 26 21:14 examples.desktop  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bogdan bogdan   18 Aug 26 21:30 Music -> /BHDD/bogdan/Music  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bogdan bogdan   21 Aug 26 21:30 Pictures -> /BHDD/bogdan/Pictures  
drwxr-xr-x 2 bogdan bogdan 4096 Aug 27 00:21 Public  
drwxr-xr-x 2 bogdan bogdan 4096 Aug 27 00:21 Templates  
drwxr-xr-x 2 bogdan bogdan 4096 Aug 27 00:21 Videos
```

Output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,ROTA,MODEL`

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,ROTA,MODEL  
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL      ROTA MODEL  
sda             477G                          0 SAMSUNG MZNTN512  
├─sda1 vfat     487M /boot/efi                0   
└─sda2 ext4   428.8G /                        0   
sdb           931.5G                          1 HGST HTS721010A9  
├─sdb1 vfat     500M            ESP           1   
├─sdb2 ext4     818G /BHDD                    1   
├─sdb3 swap     7.6G [SWAP]                   1   
├─sdb4 ntfs     852M            WINRETOOLS    1   
└─sdb5 ntfs     9.2G            Image         1
```

**Update:** Interstingly, I can download torrents to the HDD using the default client provided with 16.04 - `Transmission`

**Update2:** I installed Google Chrome today just to test whether it will be experiencing the same problem and it is not. I can save files with Chrome wherever I want, so it seems like the problem is to do with Firefox.

**Update3:** Tried resetting my Firefox profile with `mv ~/.mozilla ~/.mozilla.old` and using a clean one, however the problem still persists. Also tried reinstalling Firefox by first completely removing it from synaptic and then installing it again with synaptic. The issue is still present.

**Update4:** I have changed the ownership of /BHDD using `chown username:username /BHDD` and also set the read/write permissions using `sudo chmod 755 /BHDD`, but Firefox is still unable to save to this drive.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you already mentioned `/BHDD`.  What program gives you the error "Invalid Save permissions" ?

Comment: I get the error when I try to download something from Firefox - that is - after clicking on some download link, I get the error message immediately after pressing 'Save".

Comment: Try the instructions here: [Downloading an update, I get this message," You do not have the proper permissions. Choose another save directory". How do I choose another save directory?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/879768). I know it's about Windows, but perhaps the same solution will apply here.

Comment: I do get asked where to save it and if I choose to save it on the HDD under /BHDD, I get the the error. Otherwise I can save it wherever I want on my SSD.

Comment: Go to Firefox settings and set the default Downloads location to `/BHDD`.  OR you could use LVM (logical volume management) partitioning. But LVM means you have to redo your entire partitioning again.

Comment: Hello, @ipselute, I don't want to have a default Downloads location, because I want to choose which folder inside /BHDD I am saving to (and also sometimes I might want to save to the SSD). As I said, Google Chrome and other programs have no problems with saving to /BHDD - it is just Firefox, so I don't think that I will have to use LVM.

Comment: Then you have to change permissions for Firefox. You have to add Firefox to some group of permitted apps. Try this command: `chown -hR *your username*:users /your/directory`.

Comment: @ipselute I tried with `chown -hR username:username /BHDD` and the problem is still there. I also did just `chown -R username:username /BHDD` (without the h) - still no luck. I did a bit more searching and tried with `sudo chmod 755 /BHDD`, following [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/158735/how-to-set-permissions-so-that-i-can-read-and-write-to-another-partition) thread and again nothing. Even did `chmod 777`, but that didn't solve it either so I typed the command with 755 (assuming that it will return it back to 755).

Comment: I am completely baffled. Maybe try installing another version of Firefox ESR or contact Mozilla. Sorry i can't be of real help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just redid some of the things that I have listed above as not solving the problem and it went away - no idea why. Here is what I redid:

Reinstalled Firefox again through Synaptic - not with the button for reisntallation, but instead removed it completely and then installed it (probably no difference). I left my user files as they were, so it loaded all my extensions and options when I started it for the first time.

Afterwards, I set permissions with `sudo chmod 755 /BHDD` (which was around the 4th or 5th time of me doing it).

Then finally, I changed the ownership again with `chown -R useername:username /BHDD` and also `chown -hR useername:username /BHDD`. (I had also done these a few times).

Next, I opened Firefox and I could download stuff wherever I wanted. Black magic.

Answer (score 0):

I think it help you. I found issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/266231/466636).

First, make sure that you own the partition. Go to Media then right click on the icon then go to properties. On the middle tab you can see the owner. If it is root then open a terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+T and type the following command:

```
sudo chown --recursive [yourUserName]:[yourUserName] [pathToPartitionFolder]
```

without the [] and enter your password when asked. 
Where [pathToPartitionFolder] is something like /media/7a8s87d8. 
Try to write a file on the partition.

If you are the owner but it is not writeable then make it writeable by changing the rights on the middle tab of properties.

Comment: We were probably typing at the same time - as I said, I am not sure what did the trick - but one of the things that I have listed in my answer solved the problem.